# Working with .asp and .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp-classic, hosting

This may be the wrong place but this is new to me. I did some ASP.NET programming in VS.NET awhile ago and I always did debug in the menu to run and test the site and I always noticed that it compiled ... now I have someone having asking me to work on their ASP.NET website and my question is (new to this type of hosting) do I just edit the files and then upload them via FTP or do I have to ask the host to do a compile or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have developed a project in Visual Studio.

If this is a **Web Site** and not a Web Application:

1. Right click the project (not the solution) in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click "Publish Web Site"
3. Set the local location of where you want the Web Site published to.
4. Take the local copy and upload it to your web root of your hosting provider

If this is a **Web Application**, check to see if the hosting provider has a .axd service extension for "One-Click Publishing". If the provider does not have this feature:

1. Right click the project (not the solution) in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click "Publish..."
3. Change the Publish method to "File System"
4. Set the Target Location and click Publish
5. Take the local copy and upload it to your web root of your hosting provider

With Web Applications you also have the ability to upload via FTP, which if you have all of the FTP information at hand it should be easy enough.

Comment: So I use VS.NET to send the updated files to the shared hosting web server?

Comment: You can if they offer that functionality. Search the FAQ pages on the website of your hosting provider. If they do, then all you need is the proper service extension and log in information.